# Vue3.js and exported namespace

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuejs3

I have a code that was in a .ts file that I wanted to import into a.vue file for consistency.

In the .ts file, I have some functions inside an exported namespace.

The issue is when I keep that in the .vue file, I get the following error:

```
<script setup> cannot contain ES module exports. If you are using a previous version of <script setup>, please consult the updated RFC at https://github.com/vuejs/rfcs/pull/227
```

if I remove the export keyword, I get:

```
SyntaxError: ambiguous indirect export: ...
```

#### Structure of /path/to/file.js

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import { Stuffs } from "package";

export namespace myNS {
   // members here
}
</script>
```

#### Structure of /path/to/importer.js

```
<script setup lang="ts">

import { ref, onMounted } from "vue";
import { myNS } from "@/path/to/file.js";

//Stuffs
</script>
```

#### viteJS

```
import { fileURLToPath, URL } from "url";

import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import vue from "@vitejs/plugin-vue";

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  define: {
    __VUE_I18N_FULL_INSTALL__: true,
    __VUE_I18N_LEGACY_API__: false,
    __INTLIFY_PROD_DEVTOOLS__: false,
  },
  plugins: [vue()],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      "@": fileURLToPath(new URL("./src", import.meta.url)),
    },
  },
});
```

#### Question:

So How do I export my namespace in this context ?
What are my alternatives instead of exporting ?

I need my functions to be accessible outside of their file and called inside vue3 components.

Thanks

Comment: What you call "consistency" seems to be is a misuse. .vue files are for components, don't use them for general purposes. `<script setup lang="ts">` - this is not valid JS and should be used in Vue SFC only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You *cannot* move code from TS files into script setup by this exact reason -
**You can't use `export` in Script Setup**

That's the whole reason to use TS rather then just using Script Setup

The only thing Script Setup can export is the implicit default export of the whole component

If you want a namespace export, use TS file

If you want a namespace of components, import components as defaults from `.vue` and reexport into namespace

Comment: Ok I will step back then. I thought I could avoid multiple extensions but no.. Thanks Dimava

Comment: @LeXav well, you can avoid using *Vue* flies , but you definitely don't want that

Answer (score 1):

In your code, you are trying to export a namespace (myNS) and import from an external package.  does not support these features directly. To resolve this issue, you can consider the following approaches: Use  Block: If you need to export a namespace or use advanced ES module features, it might be best to use a regular  block instead of .

```
<script lang="ts">
import { Stuffs } from "package";

export namespace myNS {
  // members here
}
</script>
```

Comment: You mean a script block aside the script setup ? Nice, I will try that, +1 in the meantime